# Product Page Uploads and Automatic Updates

Tags: entities, ubercart

Right now my website has ubercart. I was wondering if there was a way to make it so when a user uploads a file with a description/price/etc that the product page would automatically update with their new upload.

I'm making a user based artist website. Where the users can upload their own art works and sell either a digital copy of their work or a physical copy (their choice ultimately), and I was wanting some help with the logistics of doing such a thing.

The website is currently running with Ubercart and all of its required addons AND the CorporateClean theme.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I found out more details of what exactly I am looking for. I am looking to setup a user based marketplace.

Comment: So, when you update a description or price the corresponding page still shows the previous details? Or are you looking for a 'user page' with his/her products?

Comment: I am looking for a user page with his/her products. Say SusyQ is selling XYZ and Jake is selling ABC, I want to be able to go to their individual profiles and see that SusyQ is selling XYZ and Jake is selling ABC....

Also, the ability to conglomerate everyone's products under "Categories", say both John and Susyq's products are Electronic. I want to be able to see ABC & XYZ within the "Electronics" category.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will have to alter the 'ubercart product-content type' and add some taxonomy fields to create the categories (electronics etc.). (Not sure if ubercart has this by default.)

Then you will have to use a view to override the ubercart product page. Look into views and [Contextual filters](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views). You can for instance create a block (user-product-block) and use a contextual filter to fill this. You can choose to get the user id from url and then select all products created by that user.

Filtering by category is exactly as done on the page above.